# Socket io breaks when a lot websocket connections in google chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I create 60 client connections to socket.io server in google chrome browser.
Server at specific time send screenshot to the clients. And some websocket connections, that are subprotocol of socket.io are broken, so connection at about 1-4 chrome tabs are closed. I tried to increase pingTimeout, it helped to overcome tcp transport close problem only (this problem I have as well), but this solution doesn't help to fix sending screenshot problem.

In my opinion google chrome can't support about 50-60 tabs at one time, because CPU and RAM are increased to the max values because of sending screenshots to 60 clients (each client has 2 websocket connection: the first for simple messages, the second for graphics (to send screenshots)), so chrome closes some websocket connections.

Part of code for the server socket io here:

```
// server
this.http = this._createHttpServer(sslCert, sslKey);

this.io = socketIo(this.http, {
    'pingTimeout': 180000,
    'pingInterval': 60000
});

const jwtAuth = socketioJwt.authorize({
     secret: jwtSecret,
     timeout: 15000
});

this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.once('authenticate', (data) => {
        socket.rawAuthData = data;
    });
    jwtAuth(socket);
});


// client
var connOptions = {
    "reconnectionAttempts": 2
};
var socket = io(options.url, connOptions);
socket.on('connect', function() {
    if (options.token) {
        socket.emit('authenticate', {token: options['token'], tag : tag});

        socket.on('authenticated', function() {
            ctx.printLog('Authorized. Waiting for handshake');
            socket.once('tunnel-handshake', function() {
                ctx.printLog('handshake received! connection is ready');
                processConnected();
            });
        }).on('unauthorized', function(msg) {
            ctx.printLog("Authorization failed: " + JSON.stringify(msg.data));
            eventHandlers.onerror({ code: ctx.ERROR_CODE.INVALID_TOKEN});
        });
    } else {
        processConnected();
    }
});

socket.on('reconnect_failed', eventHandlers.onerror.bind(this, {code: 1, reason: "Reconnection failed"}));
socket.on('disconnect', eventHandlers.onclose);
socket.on('error', eventHandlers.onerror);
```

Does exist any ideas, what the cause could be? Does exist any solution of this problem?
Is it google chrome problem or socket.io options problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing socket.io to 3.0 version can't resolve the issue. **socket.io v3.0** has **engine.io v4.0**. [Next information in release notes](https://socket.io/blog/engine-io-4-release/) of engine.io v4.0 describes the problem ("Heartbeat mechanism reversal" title):

> We have received a lot of reports from users that experience **random disconnects due to ping timeout**, even though their Internet connection is up and the remote server is reachable. It should be noted that in that case the client reconnects right away, but still it was an annoying issue.

> After analysis, it seems to be caused by delayed timers on the
> client-side. Those timers are used in the ping-pong mechanism which
> helps to ensure the connection between the server and the client is
> still healthy. A delay on the client-side meant the client sent the
> ping packet too late, and the server considered that the connection
> was closed.

> That’s why the ping packets will now be sent by the server, and the
> client will respond with a pong packet.

But increasing pingTimeout and pingInterval to 1073741823 value resolves the issue.